# No such command 'role' - Ansible Molecule

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, molecule

When running `molecule init role <sample_role>`

It returns with

> Error: No such command 'role'

```
Python version: 3.10.12
Ansible version: 2.15.4
OS: Windows using WSL
Molecule version: 6.0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init role` has been [removed from molecule](https://github.com/ansible/molecule/pull/3959) with [release 6.0.0](https://github.com/ansible/molecule/releases/tag/v6.0.0).

This was redundant with the [same functionality provided by `ansible-galaxy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-galaxy.html#role-init)

So if you want to init a role and a default molecule scenario inside it you should now run:

```
ansible-galaxy role init my_role
cd my_role
molecule init scenario
```

Comment: Thanks solved it! was really having hard time finding that pull request. Thanks!